# Nothing but golf?

Tags: discussion

It seems the actual challenges and puzzles are few and far between, and most of them are mislabeled anyway (anything that adds least amount of code chars as part of the problem should be labeled golf).

Is this all this place is going to be?

Comment: Related: [Golf versus non-golf questions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59/golf-versus-non-golf-questions)

Comment: Related: [Is the number of characters really all this site is about?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66/is-the-number-of-characters-really-all-this-site-is-about)

Comment: See also: [Site title and domain](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5/78).

Answer (score 2):

> anything that adds least amount of code chars as part of the problem should be labeled golf

False. A code golf is a contest where smallest code size is the *primary* (and often sole<sup>†</sup>) criterion for winning, not merely a criterion somewhere down the chain. In particular, if the primary criterion is speed, elegance, or anything else, it's not a code golf.

Contributors are welcome to post non-golf problems, as long as they aren't mislabelled as golf. There are professional code golfers (personally, I'd consider the people on the codegolf.com leader board to be such), and if this site is to have any credibility with them (since Stack Exchange is a network for expert and professional participation), then we need to treat golf as golf.

---

† Since Stack Exchange does not support multiple winners, using smallest code size as the only winning criterion on this site is not realistic. At least, a tiebreaker (such as earliest posting time) is needed.